# Practical Malware Analysis - 7_01, Push for no reason

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, stack, compiler-optimization, malware

While reading the book Practical Malware Analysis, I was doing the 7_01 exercise. Here's a link to the code and the answers - https://jmprsp.wordpress.com/2016/03/03/practical-malware-analysis-analyzing-malicious-windows-programs-lab-7-01/

There are two commands that I can't really understand what they do in the main function(code copied from IDA):

```
ServiceStartTable= SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYA ptr -10h
var_8= dword ptr -8
var_4= dword ptr -4
argc= dword ptr 4
argv= dword ptr 8
envp= dword ptr 0Ch

sub esp, 16

lea eax, [esp+10h+ServiceStartTable]

mov [esp+10h+ServiceStartTable.lpServiceName], offset aMalservice

push eax

mov [esp+14h+ServiceStartTable.lpServiceProc], offset second_function

mov [esp+14h+var_8], 0

mov [esp+14h+var_4], 0

call ds:StartServiceCtrlDispatcherA

push 0

push 0

call second_function

add esp, 24

retn
```

second_function is the function sub_401040 that is shown in the link above, it does not get any arguments and there is no reason for those 2 pushes of zero. Can anyone please explain this? If I had to guess I would say that the compiler put those pushes there for whatever reason, but I don't know why

Comment: Which function in particular? The ones I see there do take arguments.

Comment: I added the code for the main, I didn't see that it wasn't in the link but I wrote it from what I saw while disassembling in IDA

Comment: The link only contains a small part of the `sub_401040`, it may still use arguments.

Comment: If a function is called with arguments, the compiler provides those arguments. It is irrelevant whether the function uses the arguments or not.

Comment: The second picture in the link shows the beginning of sub_401040, it does not look like there are any arguments that the function takes(not at least according to IDA). If the function doesn't take them it appears like those zeros that were pushed are of no use

Comment: Why do you think they would need to be in the beginning? Also, it may be a particular implementation of a function prototype that just doesn't happen to use the arguments. Still, the caller must pass them.

Comment: Still why would you pass them? Our teacher told us that there is a valid reason those pushes are there, he gave us a hint saying it has something to do with the program returning to the Main after the function is done(which it shouldn't because the function was designed to run forever) but if somehow it does return to the main then those parameters are required, yet I still can't find a reason for them being there

Answer (score 0):

I think, this application must be run as a Service, but you can force it to run by setting the instruction pointer direct to the main function sub_401040.